# How do I check if a parameter is not null and then update a variable

Tags: solidity

I created a function to update some variables. I want to check if a parameter is passed or not null and then update the variable.

```
   function updateProfile(
        string memory _name,
        GENDER _gender
    ) public onlyOwner {
        if (_name) {
            patientInfo.name = _name;
        }
 
        if (_gender) {
            patientInfo.name = _gender;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to check if an input parameter is null. You'll have to check if it's the empty state of each corresponding data type. For `uint` check if it's 0. For `string` check if its `bytes(string).length` is 0. For `address` check if its `address(0)`. For enum, this won't work because the first type is an enum is given index 0. So assuming your GENDER enum definition is as follows

```js
enum GENDER {
    male,
    female
}
```

Its not possible to check if there is a valid input as even a missing input (0) points to a valid index (male). So to handle this, you can create another type in the enum at index zero, which is not supposed to be used for a valid input.

```js
enum GENDER {
    invalid
    male,
    female
}
```

Now, empty input will match the `invalid` type so you can just check for that. Your code could be like this in the end

```
function updateProfile(
    string memory _name,
    GENDER _gender
) public onlyOwner {
    if (bytes(_name).length!=0) {
        patientInfo.name = _name;
    }
    if (_gender!=GENDER.invalid) {
        patientInfo.gender = _gender;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. You can read up about the zero value for different data types for further clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the string by casting it to bytes then check the length which will determine the parameter value available or not.

```
function updateProfile(
    string memory _name,
) public onlyOwner {
    if (bytes(_name).length > 0) {
        patientInfo.name = _name;
    }
}
```